# Issue with Search result - Xcode project

Tags: ios, uitableview, search, firebase

I'm working on iOS application using swift and firebase:

I tried to add search bar to a table view as the following code:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableVC: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating  {

var resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
//var filteredUsers = [nsdi]()

var filteredUsers: NSMutableArray = []
var UserNamesArray: NSMutableArray = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
//        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
//        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
//        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
//        //self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeThatFits()
    
    
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        
        return controller
    })()
    
    
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    
    let ref = Firebase(url: "https://hissah-1st-fb-test.firebaseio.com/Users")
    
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("Job").queryEqualToValue("Programs")
        .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary{
                //print("dict====== \(dict)")
                
                for (key,value) in dict {
                    let mainDict = NSMutableDictionary()
                    mainDict.setObject(key, forKey: "userid")

                    if let dictnew = value as? NSMutableDictionary{
                        
                        if let metname = dictnew["UserName"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "UserName")
                        }
                        if let metname = dictnew["Details"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "Details")
                        }
                        if let metname = dictnew["Email"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "Email")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    //print("mainDict========= \(mainDict)")
                    
                    self.UserNamesArray.addObject(mainDict)
                    
                }
                //print("UserNamesArray ==== \(self.UserNamesArray)")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        })
}





// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if self.resultSearchController.active
   {
    return self.filteredUsers.count
    }else
   {
    return UserNamesArray.count
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    
    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
       // cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] as? String
        
        
        if let name = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = name["UserName"] as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = name["Details"] as? String
        }

        
    }
    else{
    
    
    if let name = UserNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = name["UserName"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = name["Details"] as? String
    }
    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
        let detailsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewController") as! DetailsVC
        
        if let name = self.UserNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{
            
            detailsViewController.self.strUserid = name["userid"] as? String
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredUsers.removeAllObjects()
    
    //attributeA contains[cd] $A OR attributeB contains[cd]
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "UserName contains[cd] %@ OR Details contains[cd] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!,searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (UserNamesArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    for type in array {
        // Do something
        
        filteredUsers .addObject(type)
    }
    
   // filteredUsers = array as! [String]
    
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}



 }
```

Here's the table view:
[image]

When the user clicks at any item, it retreives the information for that item from firebase, if I clicked on Sara for example, it gives her name and her email as here:
[image]

When I search for example for mariah or hello, it gives the right result, as here:
[image]

But if I clicked on the result Item, it always retrieves the information of the first item!'Sara's Information', for example the result mariah, gives this:
[image]

Can anyone tell me, how can I fix this? and why is this happing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you are not setting return array of search result at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. so you set `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code like following:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        if self.resultSearchController.active
        {

            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                let detailsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewControllerroller") as! DetailsViewController

                if let name = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{

                    detailsViewController.self.strUserid = name["userid"] as? String
                }

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true)

            }

        }
        else
        {
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                let detailsViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsViewControllerroller") as! DetailsViewController

                if let name = self.UserNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{

                    detailsViewController.self.strUserid = name["userid"] as? String
                }

                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsViewController, animated: true)

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRow` you are checking if user is actively searching and filtering result

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {


        if let name = self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{
        // other code
    }
    else{
      ..// here get data from original array

    if let name = UserNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{


    return cell
}
```

> However while in `didSelectRow` method you are not using the same flow

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


   if let name = self.UserNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary{
```

This is why you are getting wrong result.
you need to also check if the searchController is active here

```
    if self.resultSearchController.active
    {
       //get from filteredUsers
    }
    else{ 
       //get from original users
    }
```